# macOS: AVAssetWriter crash upon markAsFinished / finishWriting

Tags: swift, macos, avassetwriter, avassetwriterinput

Using `AVAssetWriter` to save captured audio and video to a file. **It works correctly** on my own machines all the time, but Apple's App Review team reports a crash when finishing recording.

In the report the thread crashes upon `finishWriting(completionHandler:)`.

My code to stop writing:

```
    var videoWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    var audioWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    var videoWriter: AVAssetWriter!
    var isRecording = false

    func stopVideoWriter() async {
        guard isRecording else { return }
        isRecording = false

        videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
        audioWriterInput.markAsFinished()

        videoWriter.finishWriting { [self] in
            videoWriter = nil
            videoWriterInput = nil
            audioWriterInput = nil
        }
    }
```

Some SO posts mention to check `videoWriter.status` before stopping, but this does not seem to help at all. Also there is no documentation that shows it is necessary to check the status before finishing.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriter/1390432-finishwriting) for `finishWriting(completionHandler:)` mentions the following:

> To ensure the asset writer finishes writing all samples, call this
> method only after all calls to append(*:) or
> append(*:withPresentationTime:) return.

The app works fine on my own testing machines, so I cannot confirm that this is the actual part where the crash happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: The crash is almost certainly related to using implicitly unwrapped optionals (i.e. ending in `!`). You should should almost certainly get rid of those and replace them with normal types (without `!`). You don't show code for how you ensure that those are always non-nil at this point. If there is any possibility at all that they are nil, then this code will (correctly) crash.

Comment: @hotdogsoup.nl Did you solve this? I face same problem